# API Testing Tool

Tags: software-development, web-development, api

I'm having problems with Postman and not getting any meaningful help from their support.

Could someone recommend a nice API testing tool? Thanks.

P.S. The issue I'm having with Postman is that it's not sending the cookie with API calls. Here's my previous post about this issue: [Postman is not using cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008640/postman-is-not-using-cookie).

Comment: Did you try asking on [Slack](https://www.getpostman.com/slack-invite)? Although I don't use cookies, I have not found anything free which even comes close to Postman. Don't give up on it too soon.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've been super happy with Postman. I'll try Slack!